# How to check for the log file when an error occurs while installing a python package

Tags: python3, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pip

I'm trying to install Networkit package in Windows subsystem for linux. I did

```
python3.7 -m pip install networkit
```

and the following error occurs

```
compilation terminated.
    CMakeFiles/sparsification.dir/build.make:81: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/sparsification.dir/networkit/sparsification.cpp.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/sparsification.dir/networkit/sparsification.cpp.o] Error 1
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1395: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/sparsification.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/sparsification.dir/all] Error 2
    Makefile:148: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    Build tool returned an error, exiting setup.py
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-pq3f9z1t/networkit/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-pq3f9z1t/networkit/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-zex8gap3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/user/.local/include/python3.7m/networkit Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm not sure where to look for the logs.
Could someone suggest how to find the path in which I have to look for the log file?

Comment: im not sure that is what you are looking for (its not the logs file) - but it can show you your logs during trying to run user process on your os, check the command `journalctl -f | grep -i <namefilter>` -f flag is for live logs following and you can use the grep command to filter that out, if you are looking for kernel logs then you can add -k flag.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a log file at the command line when running pip using the `--log LOG_FILE` argument. For example, `pip install click --log LOG_FILE`. Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53844983/1789708).